# Prevent Apollo caching requests for some operations

Tags: next.js, apollo-client

I'm using Apollo Client experimental getClient in a next.js app.

```
export const { getClient } = registerApolloClient(
  () =>
    new ApolloClient({
      cache: new InMemoryCache(),
      link: new HttpLink({
        uri: `${apiBaseUrl}/graphql`,
      }),
    }),
);
```

I'm using it to handle my login mutation like so:

```
const { data } = await getClient().mutate({
  mutation: LOGIN_MUTATION,
  variables: {
    email,
    password,
  },
  fetchPolicy: "network-only",
});
```

Unfortunately, the `fetchPolicy` property doesn't seem to work: the token returned by my server is always the same, therefore making it impossible to sign in.

The only workaround I found so far is to update my client declaration to include this:

```
fetchOptions: { cache: "no-store" },
```

But obviously, I'd like to cache the result of some of my queries.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the server cache has no regard for the `fetchPolicy` option. Instead, you'll need to use this:

```
const { data } = await getClient().mutate({
  mutation: MY_MUTATION,
  variables: {
    myVariable,
  },
  context: {
    fetchOptions: {
      // Do not cache the result of login mutation
      next: { revalidate: 0 },
    },
  },
});
```

This ensures that the data is always revalidated.

Comment: fetch-policy only applies to the client cache. There was no mention of a server-side cache.